# How ${@: -1} expand to last argument

Tags: bash

I knows the `${para:[start]:[length]}` and `$@` notation but I'm unable to find out how `${var: -1}` evaluates to the last argument.

Comment: As a side note, this should not be confused with `{para:-1}` which is explained in [\[ this \]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) page. Note the use of  `()` in @andlrc 's answer and see the comments that follow..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider it as `length - 1` which will resolve in the last character in `$var`. Same goes for `${var:(-2)}`, ...:

```
var='hello'
printf "%s\n" "${var:(-1)}" # o
printf "%s\n" "${var:(-2)}" # lo
printf "%s\n" "${var:(-3)}" # llo
```

Comment: You can also simply use whitespace to distinguish between `${var:-1}` and `${var: -1}`.

Comment: @chepner I know but as you can see below that can easily misread as `${var:-1}`. Better be explicit IMO

Answer (score 3):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> If parameter is @ ... an offset  of
>                 -1  evaluates to the last positional parameter.